# Installing DirectX on XP

Tags: installation, directx, windows-xp

I would like to install DirectX on Win XP to try writing some tiny graphic program.
Without administrator's privileges I have been allowed to install CodeBlocks and Eclipse (even if I didn't understand how Eclipse works).

Where could I find the **last DirectX version available for XP** (I read that there is an unofficial DirectX 10 version for XP)
and above all a **step-to-step guide** to install it in Eclipse or in Codeblocks?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

DirectX 9.0c is the last version of DirectX supported for Windows. It is built-in with Windows XP Service Pack 2 and Windows XP Service Pack 3.

In fact, the phrase "install DirectX" doesn't actually mean anything on all versions of Windows since Windows XP Service Pack 2. The legacy *DirectX End User Runtime* copies some utility libraries like D3DX, but it never modifies the version of DirectX on your system. See [Not So Direct Setup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup.aspx)

The 'unofficial Direct3D 10' thing was a hack that just copied some DLLs around. Since Windows XP doesn't support the WDDM driver model they can't actually use the latest graphics feature exposed by Direct3D 10. You really can't write a DIrect3D 10 app correctly using them.

If you want a newer version of DirectX, move to a newer version of Windows.

[Upgrade to Windows 8.1 from Windows Vista or Windows XP](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-from-windows-vista-xp-tutorial)